Mutually exclusive non-zero variables in Linear Programming, without using binary variables or objective function
First, apologies for the probably terrible title. I could not think of a better one.
I am creating an LP model in which all variables are non-negative. I have the following constraints:
$$a - b = c - d$$
$$e + a = c$$
$$e + b = d$$
$c$ actually has a known fixed value.
My problem is that $a$ gets the full value of $c$ and $b$ gets the full value of $d$.
e.g. If $c = 10$ and $d = 15$, then $a = 10$ and $b = 15$. I want to get to a situation where only one of $a$ and $b$ is non-zero.
Is it possible to force only one of $a$ and $b$ to be non-zero without using binary variables or including any of these variables in the objective function?
In other words, when $c = 10$ and $d = 15$, I would like $a = 0$ and $b = 5$.

The disjunction $a = 0 \lor b = 0$ is nonconvex, so you cannot enforce it with linear constraints.
